# How to return a CSV file with status code from a .Net Core Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I have created WebAPI using .NetCore 6.0.  The API will receive a csv file and return the results as a csv file.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Search")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Search(IFormFile file)
    {
    
        StringBuilder sb  = await GetList(int id);
        return File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
    }
```

But I would like to return a status code along with result data. Thank you.

Comment: Which exactly status code you want to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use of Ok() method from ControllerBase class, which your controller should extend.

```
return Ok(File(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName));
```